# What does 話 mean here?

Tags: translation

> キノック 「なあ　アーロン　この10年　なにをしていた？
>
> アーロン 「作戦が始まる　そんな話はいいだろう
>
> キノック 「どうせ失敗する作戦だ 「少しでも長く夢を見させてやるさ

It's from the game Final Fantasy X, the scene before Operation Mi'ihen. It's the operation to destroy the creature "Sin", the world evil. Kinoc (キノック) is in charge of the operation. Both Aaron (アーロン) and Kinoc know that operation is doomed.

I can't understand that 話 means in this context.

Does Aaron refer to this question - "この10年　なにをしていた？", then 話 would mean "talk" or he refers to this part - "作戦が始まる" and then 話 would mean "state of affairs"?

My translation:

> Kinoc: Tell me, Aaron. What have you been doing these ten years?
>
> Aaron: The operation begins. **I quess you're pleased with it's going
>   like that.**

OR

> **I wonder if such a talk would be appropriate.**
>
> Kinoc: It's a failure plan anyway. We'll let them dream just a little
>   longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そんな話 refers to the topic of アーロンがこの10年何をしていたか.
The 話 is more like 話題, topic.

～はいい(だろう) here means "Forget about..." "Never mind..."
いい can mean "not important" "doesn't matter" (どうでもいい) or "unnecessary" "enough" (もういい).
eg 「その話はもう**いい**。」"Let's not discuss it anymore."
「皿洗いなんか**いい**から。」"Forget about washing-up."

> Kinoc: Tell me, Aaron. What have you been doing these ten years?
>
> Aaron: The(=Our) operation begins (now / soon). Forget about it (=the topic of what I've been doing)
>   (Implying it's not the right time to talk about it. And using そんな makes it sound like he doesn't really want to talk about it)
>
> Kinoc: It's a failure plan anyway. We'll let them dream just a little longer.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without the full context. Judging from the last line, I would go for option 1. Something like:

ー Can I ask you what you did for the past 10years? (Ironic, implying ''you did not do much, did you?")

ー My grand plan is almost in motion. Leave me alone. / stop bothering me. (the nuance here being '' stop implying that I did nothing, as my plan is soon to bring great results ")

ー I'm sure that "great plan" will fail... but I'll allow you to daydream a little while longer (more irony there)

Perhaps confirm that it works with the full context?